# Is there a way to have custom content with mezzanie/Django

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm  new using Mezzanine and figured out how to set-up pages where I can manage content from Admin page.
But I have static pages, where I want to store some content and being able to control that content from Admin page.

Is this something I can do with Mezzanine?

I imagine that I need to create a model with richtext field add that model to admin interface and than somehow access to that model through templatage.

But any exact example would greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs on [creating custom content types](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#creating-custom-content-types). The primary approach is to subclass the `Page` model and add your custom fields.

Alternatively, if your custom content is conceptually independent from your pages, it might make sense to create independent models with [relational fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) to the `RichTextPage` model and edit them through [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).

Note that the mezzanine docs on custom content types and the django docs on inlines use the same author/book example so you can easily compare the two strategies.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with having my own model with RickTextField and create a templateage to be used in templates.